# Move defunct gmail ActiveSync calendar entries (iOS) to gmail cal

Tags: ios, gmail, google-calendar, exchange-activesync

My father-in-law set up gmail ActiveSync on an old iPhone a long time ago and continues to add calendar dates to it even though it is defunct. He's upgraded iPhones to a 6s but still has that old account as his default.

**Question**: How do I get those calendar entries off of a non-syncing account and move them to a regular google calendar account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method I found was to purchase and use [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/). I backed up the phone and then exported as vCards and calendar files to the attached computer. Then I imported them into google calendar and contacts for them (they were moving to Android).